# How to fix takeUpToNumLeft StopIteration in pyspark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

Something strange with python 3.7.0 and spark 2.3.0.

Using the above version we get the following exception:

```
19/08/10 21:29:10 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 13, 172.16.138.199, executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1354, in takeUpToNumLeft
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 229, in main
    process()
  File "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 224, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 372, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

Why we get the above exception? and how  to fix it?

Comment: can you provide your spark snippet?

Comment: @DennisLi, the code is very big, i wanna add the snippet  where the code will be stuck.By the way the same function is applied to data1 is work well and and in the same application when it is called with data2 raises the above execption

Comment: sure, just add the snippet that caused problem.